# PHP htmlentities with trim producing unusual result - removes number 3

Tags: php, html-entities

I feel this may be a bug but it could also be a little known quirk of PHP's htmlentities and trim used in conjunction.

This code will work fine with whatever data sent into it:

```
// Number is normally accessed using $_Post[], hard coded for example
$rating = htmlentities(trim('3'));
```

However if you add the ENT_QUOTES parameter to htmlentities you will get a very unexpected result:

```
// Number is normally accessed using $_Post[], hard coded for example
$rating = htmlentities(trim('3',ENT_QUOTES));          // Returns ''
$rating = htmlentities(trim('3123',ENT_QUOTES));       // Returns 12
$rating = htmlentities(trim('test3123',ENT_QUOTES));   // Returns test312
```

**Does anyone know what is causing this bug?** It seems to be a hard coded issue in PHP so I'll just work around this but i am curious to what htmlentities is doing to cause this.

PS - I'm using PHP version 5.5.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed parentheses incorrectly. In your case you are passing `ENT_QUOTES` as second parameter of [trim](http://php.net/trim). The `ENT_QUOTES` constant is set to `3` so trim removes `3`.

`ENT_QUOTES` should instead be second argument of [htmlentities](https://php.net/htmlentities):

```
htmlentities(trim('3'), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Comment: I feel so dumb now. My fault for using a massive find and replace to speed up coding.